# PYSPARK ERROR: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

Getting the below error while creating any sample dataframe:

> 24/03/10 11:30:40 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (Siva executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

Attached Environment Variables:
[image]

Attached Path Variables:
[image]